# How to compare the number groupings and return the largest number?

Tags: string, parsing, rust, numbers, compare

```rust
fn solve(s: &str) -> u32 {
    s.split(char::is_alphabetic)
        .map(|num| num.parse::<u32>().unwrap())
        .max()
        .unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(solve("gh12cdy695m1"), 695);
}
```

I dont understand why Im getting this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: Empty }', src/main.rs:3:39
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 5):

`split` will yield strings between *every* alphabetic character even when there's nothing between them:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("gh12cdy695m1");
    for num in s.split(char::is_alphabetic) {
        println!("{:?}", num);
    }
}
```

```
""
""
"12"
""
""
"695"
"1"
```

You should filter out these empty strings before attempting to parse them:

```
fn solve(s: &str) -> u32 {
    s.split(char::is_alphabetic)
        .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        .map(|num| num.parse::<u32>().unwrap())
        .max()
        .unwrap()
}
```